# Google AdSense ads per page limitations

Tags: google-adsense

In the Google's [Ad placement policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Google_ad_limit_per_page) stated that the limitation is 
"up to 3". However there are lots of sites having 6 or even more ads per one single page. Moreover on some site there is information that the [limitation is actually - 6](http://www.bloggeristan.com/2013/12/adsense-ads-per-page.html).

So I'm a bit confused. How the things in real?

Comment: I am here just wondering, what makes you trust some random blogger with a 90s-themed site over official Google provided guidelines? Even then, if you read it correctly he mentions himself: `However you may not be allowed to show more than 3 Link units per page as a normal AdSense Publisher.`.

Comment: @edvinas.me It was just an example. I'd trust official docs, but I trust my eyes: as I mentioned above there is sites with lots of AdSense ads.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking at- but the Google limitation is for AdSense ads and does not include ads from other ad networks as far as I know. That is- with some limitation. Google does seem to check these too, but respects your right to have more than one advertising network and just wants to limit the ad/content ratio to something of value to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Yo can have **3 link units** and **3 ad units** per page, as described in their [support documentation](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ads_on_the_same_page_or_site_as_another_publisher):

> Please keep in mind that a maximum of three standard ad units, three link units, and two search boxes may be placed on one webpage.

Also these limitations are enforced upon **normal AdSense Publishers**, I believe premium accounts include a larger number of ad & link units.